# COM Object - Closed Dataset

Tags: oracle, delphi, debugging, com, dataset

I am working on a Delphi project. It is an application that calls a computation engine (in Delphi), which retrieves data from an Oracle Database. The project works, but I have trouble with the debugging.

To debug the engine, I create a COM Object with the dll of the computation engine; I make the application call the localhost (ie the engine running in my COM Object). Then I start the engine from the code (pressing Start in the IDE), and start the app, which calls the engine. It usually works like a charm - the code stops at the breakpoints I set in the engine code.

But since a few days, everytime I try to to that, I get an error message generated by the fact that a Dataset.State=dsInactive. I have not changed anything in the code though; the flow is opened between the database and my computer (I ping and telnet are ok).

Do you know what can cause this problem?

Thank you very much for your help!

**EDIT 1 :** 
Thank you so much MartynA for your answer!

What you describe is indeed what I was trying to say - for the beggining of it at least: I did load my project which generates the .dll into the IDE, compile it and put a breakpoint, but my breakpoint was where the error message appeared:

```
     procedure TRNParameters.SetDataset(ADataset: TClientDataSet);

begin
      if ADataset = nil then
        TRNException.RaiseTechnicalException('Erreur à la création de l''objet TRNParameters : le dataset des paramètres est nil');

      if ADataset.State = dsInactive then
        TRNException.RaiseTechnicalException('Erreur à la création de l''objet TRNParameters : le dataset des paramètres est fermé');
```

The message I get is the second one, and the breakpoint on that line is indeed reached - the code goes in that "if" - at the moment just before the message is displayed.

I checked the call stack and I get :

```
URNParams.TRNParameters.SetDataset($31345F0)
URNParams.TRNParameters.Create(???,nil)
SCEPlgFRObjectImpl.TSCEPlgFRObject.MtsDataModuleCreate(???)
:02ce0a2a TDataModule.DoCreate + $2E
:02ce086c TDataModule.Create + $E0
:02d31b70 TRemoteDataModule.Create + $38
:02d792af TComponentFactory.CreateComObject + $F
:02ccda34 TComObjectFactory.CreateInstance + $1C
:02d79211 TComponentFactory.CreateInstance + $C5
:75c58bc6 ; C:\windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
:75c73060 ; C:\windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
:7662a419 ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\COMSVCS.DLL
:7662ad82 ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\COMSVCS.DLL
:7662adf9 ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\COMSVCS.DLL
:7662ae0f ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\COMSVCS.DLL
:7662aea1 ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\COMSVCS.DLL
:7662af94 ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\COMSVCS.DLL
:765d93ca ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\COMSVCS.DLL
:765d93aa ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\COMSVCS.DLL
:7666b7ee ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\COMSVCS.DLL
:7666b9d2 ; C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\COMSVCS.DLL
:76271287 msvcrt._itow_s + 0x4c
:76271328 msvcrt._endthreadex + 0x6c
:7594343d kernel32.BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12
:778e9802 ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63
:778e97d5 ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36
```

So I guess the problem comes from the line SCEPlgFRObjectImpl.TSCEPlgFRObject.MtsDataModuleCreate(???). So I have put a breakpoint in MtsDataModuleCreate, and I eventually got to a more precise error message :

```
    try
    OraSessionFRA_SPU.Open;
  except
    on e: Exception do
    begin
      WriteLog('SCEPlgFR - ConnectDatabase : ConnectString=' + OraSessionFR_SPU.ConnectString);
      WriteLog('SCEPlgFR - ConnectDatabase : ' + e.Message);
      raise Exception.Create('SCEPlgFR - ConnectDatabase : ' + #13#10 + e.Message);
    end;
  end;
```

But! The message is inaccessible (due to optimization)!
Do you know how I can manage to read that message?

Also, I don't know how to find where the COM object is created, is it a piece of code that is supposed to be in my Delphi code? (sorry I am very new to Delphi and the COM objects!)

Thank you so much for your help!

**EDIT 2**

Hi all, 
I created a string variable Mess and added a `Mess:=e.Message` to catch the error message. I got a 'ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified'.

I guess I'll be able to find my way from this. 
Thank you so much MartynA, you're my superhero!

**EDIT 3**
Hi all, 
Here is the resolution of the problem: my Delphi couldn't find a TNS with the needed connexion. (Maybe because of conflicting installs that I had to make to develop different softwares working with different oracle pilots).
So the reason the dataset couldn't be open is because the connexion to the database was impossible (because no access to the right TNS). A colleague made me create a TNS_ADMIN environment variable which path directed to the wanted TNS. It solved my problem.

Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Is the COM object usually hosted on your local machine.  If it is, you should be able to catch the error in the IDE (see my attempted answer); if it isn't, have you tried using the remote debugger?  Which OS and Delphi version, btw?

Comment: Glad you found the solution.  Now that you know it, it might be worth spending a bit of time with the debugger to see if you could have eventually tracked it down that was.

Comment: Yes, good idea, I'll definitely do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to speculate on what could have caused the change in behaviour of your app:  if you want help with that, you would need to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Problem is, of course, that if you could provide an MCVE you would know enough to identify and fix the problem anyway.

But I think you should be able to locate and fix the error yourself in a quite straightforward way by debugging the .DLL from within the Delphi IDE:

You should be able to debug this from within the IDE:

- Load your project which generates the .Dll into the IDE, compile it and put a breakpoint at the point where it creates the COM object.
- Then, start whatever process invokes the COM object and the breakpoint should trip, so you can create execution from there.

Have you tried that?  It may be that this is what you are trying to say in your q, except that you say "Then I start the engine from the code (pressing Start in the IDE), and start the app, which calls the engine." which doesn't sound right if the COM object is hosted in a DLL.

If creation of the COM object results in an exception, the debugger should catch that so you can see from the call stack (using View | Debug Windows | Call stack) exactly where the exception is occurring.  Usually, just looking down the call stack should be sufficient to identify where the cause.

Comment: Hi MartynA, Thank you so much for your comment! I edited my message to answer your questions, and to post what I got thanks to your advice. Do you think you could help me some more? :)